# How can I make vertically resizable <div>s?

Tags: css, vuejs2

[image]

How can I make vertically resizable `<div>`s? Their height is fixed, therefore their content should become scrollable.

Comment: Alright, what did you tried so far?

Comment: @kissu not much, I have no idea on how to do that. Do image you can see is just a quick edited Vuetify example.

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not a coding service. If you want to edit the visuals of your website, you will need to learn some CSS to efficiently achieve your goal here. Some effort is required from your side and just asking how to achieve some horizontally resizable cards is not enough as you can guess. Check some CSS course online or try your luck on Vuetify's documentation.

Comment: @kissu I obviously already checked the Vuetify documentation, but I didn't find anything useful about resizing. I even checked Vuetify GitHub open issues, but no luck. That's why I decided to write my question here.

Comment: Still, my previous point is valid. Check the rules and you'll see that a "how to" is forbidden here.

Comment: It is not a vue problem but a css problem. To achieve horizontal boxes have a look at display flex or alternativ on display inline-block and set a fixed height to the elements. Makte the boxes overflow:hidden and  overflow-y: auto;. If you are using bootstrap css then a row with cols will solve your problem (it useses display flex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't want to reinvent the wheel, I used [this](https://github.com/antoniandre/splitpanes) Vue component. While it kinda works, I'd like to point out a couple of things:

- `v-model` is not supported.
- Panes size is not saved inside local storage.

Answer (score 0):

On the container where you have the text you can try to add this code:

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

If you set a fixed height for the container, now with overflow: hidden you will hide everything go outside of the container, and with overflow-y: scroll you will allow a vertical scroll to this container where you have the text